# How to use QtQuick tiled canvas?

Tags: qt, canvas, qml, qt5.4

I found a document [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html#tiled-canvas) but it's too ambiguous to understand. Who can give me some example of using tiled `Canvas`?

**UPDATE**
Now tiled `Canvas` is marked obsoleted. We should *NOT* use it any more.

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: The documentation is pretty terrible for this, I agree.

Comment: so who can use qml canvas well? who can give me an example?

Comment: I'd create a bug report on the tracker that says that the documentation is lacking. Judging from existing reports, it's not such a high priority, though: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-33129

Comment: Where is Canvas marked as obsolete?

Comment: @Mitch It's tiled `Canvas` not `Canvas`

Comment: The properties `canvasWindow` and `tileSize` are [deprecated](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas-obsolete.html), not the whole `Canvas` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mitch comment we know that tiled `Canvas` does not always work properly (see [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-33129)).

The bug still appears in Qt 5.4.2 as shown by this example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    Flickable {
        id: flick
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: 400
        contentHeight: 40000
    }
    Canvas {
        parent: flick
        anchors.fill: parent
        contextType: "2d"
        canvasSize: Qt.size(flick.contentWidth, flick.contentHeight)
        canvasWindow: Qt.rect(flick.contentX, flick.contentY,
                              flick.width, flick.height)
        tileSize: Qt.size(20, 20)
        renderStrategy: Canvas.Cooperative
        onPaint: {
            for (var y = region.y; y < region.y + region.height;
                 y += tileSize.height) {
                for (var x = region.x; x < region.x + region.width;
                     x += tileSize.width) {
                    context.fillStyle = "black";
                    context.fillRect(x, y, tileSize.width, tileSize.height);
                    context.fillStyle = "green";
                    context.fillRect(x + 1, y + 1, tileSize.width - 2,
                                     tileSize.height - 2);
                }
            }
        }
        onCanvasWindowChanged: requestPaint()
    }
}
```